# TFS plugin for "Qt Creator"

Tags: qt, plugins

Are there any TFS plugins available for the **qt creator** IDE?

Comment: ["Out of scope"](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-3832)

Comment: That only means there won't be canonical support for this. But anyone can write a plugin, as has happened since op asked the question. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt Creator supports perforce, git, mercurial, subversion and cvs as version control systems.

Answer (score 3):

Same question in Qt Forums: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/40225

Answer: There's a plugin on oktet.net: http://www.oktet.net/2014/02/04/team-foundation-server-plugin-for-qt-creator/

I personally haven't tried it so I can't comment on quality or usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

It also supports Bazaar and ClearCase.

Comment: **what** also supports these?